# how to get a text from xpath in c#

Tags: c#, xpath

i want to show data from my xml file and
this is my xml file

```html
<table>
  <tr class="even">
 <td class="ltid">1</td>
 <td class="ltn">لستر سیتی</td>
 <td class="ltg">31</td>
 <td class="ltw">19</td>
 <td class="ltd">9</td>
 <td class="ltl">3</td>
 <td class="ltgf">54</td>
    <td class="ltga">31</td>
    <td class="ltgd" dir="ltr">+23</td>
    <td class="ltp">66</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ltid">2</td>
    <td class="ltn">تاتنهام</td>
    <td class="ltg">31</td>
    <td class="ltw">17</td>
    <td class="ltd">10</td>
    <td class="ltl">4</td>
    <td class="ltgf">56</td>
    <td class="ltga">24</td>
    <td class="ltgd" dir="ltr">+32</td>
    <td class="ltp">61</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ltid">3</td>
    <td class="ltn">آرسنال</td>
    <td class="ltg">30</td>
    <td class="ltw">16</td>
    <td class="ltd">7</td>
    <td class="ltl">7</td>
    <td class="ltgf">48</td>
    <td class="ltga">30</td>
    <td class="ltgd" dir="ltr">+18</td>
    <td class="ltp">55</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and i want to get the third team so
 i want to get `'<td class="ltid">3</td>'`
and this is the code i tried

```
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(richTextBox2.Text);
        var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
        var contentCell = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='ltid']");
        txtTeam.Text = contentCell.Value;
```

but i don't know how to get the third td with this class value
i searched for find an answer but i couldn't find answer
and i wrote an another code before this one but in first `<tr>` we have 3 so it just find that from first `<tr>` not the third `<tr>`
please help me to get value from third `<tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way :

```
(//td[@class='ltid'])[3]
```

The XPath will return the 3rd occurrence of `td[@class='ltid']` from the entire XML document.

Comment: it say this:     Additional information: '//td[@class='ltid'])[3]' has an invalid token.

Comment: You missed the opening parentheses `(` at the beginning : `(//td[@class='ltid'])[3]`

Comment: it worked but it backed from the first 'tr' again not the third 'tr

Comment: The first `tr` only have one `td` which class equals `ltid`. So it is impossible that the XPath return `td` from the first `tr` given XML in the question..

Comment: i wrote my code and you can test it it all back from the first 'tr'

Comment: @Avenger It returns `<td class="ltid">3</td>` which resides in the 3rd `tr`, see the demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/etB4JX

Comment: thank you for answer and i m sorry you were right but my problem was about the next line of my code, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 ways you could do this:

```
xpath 1: //tr[3]/td[@class='ltid']
xpath 2: //td[@class='ltid'])[3]
xpath 3: //td[contains(text()='3')]
```

Comment: the problem is '3' already is in first tr and these way just back 3 from the first tr not the third tr

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see that, you could then try //tr[3]/td[contains(@class,'ltid') and contains(text(),'3')].
Did you try the first xath there? That one should work for what you are looking for. Also, you might want to download Firebug/Firepath which is a firefox plugin which you can use to get xpaths automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select("//td[@class='ltid']");
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    // do whatever you want with your item
}
```